# Error: no match for operator << in std::cout (I have already overloaded the << operator)

Tags: c++, overloading

So while working on this assignment I got stuck because I got this error. I have done operator overloading before so this came as a surprise.

```
class RGB
{
public:

    RGB(float r1, float g1, float  b1);
    RGB(RGB const& color); //copy constructor
    RGB();

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, RGB& color);
    friend istream& operator>>(istream& is, RGB& color);

    friend float r();
    friend float g();
    friend float b();
private:
    float r, g, b;
};

//Something something

RGB::RGB(float r1, float g1, float b1){
    r = r1;
    g = g1;
    b = b1;
}

//Something something

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const RGB& color){    // << Overloading
    return os<<"Red: "<<color.r<<endl<<"Green: "<<color.g<<endl<<"Blue: "<<color.b<<endl;
}
```

And this is in main

```
int main()
{
    RGB mycolor(1,2,3);
    cout<<mycolor;

return 0;
}
```

So the aforementioned error appears, can't seem to find what's wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You are missing some includes and std::ostream/std::istream (the std) and please do not fix it with using namespace std

Comment: I'm using strouspup's std_lib_facilities and I don't need the std::foo. Again, I've already done this in another assignment for a vector class that looked pretty much the same as this one but now it won't work.

Answer (score 2):

I believe there is a mis-match between your declaration and definition.
You declaration takes a `RGB& color` while your definition takes a `const RGB& color`. Try to declare `operator <<` like this:

```
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const RGB& color);
```

Answer (score 1):

The declaration you've provided is

```
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, RGB& color);
```

And the definition you've provided is

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const RGB& color)
//                               ^^^^^
```

Notice the difference?

Comment: Wooops! Too bad that it produces the same error even after the change.

Comment: @AkisKiraleos [No, it doesn't](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fabbd7f29d284806). Or the [other way around](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a742b9ae99fb219d) (don't do this, add `const` to the declaration).

Comment: @AkisKiraleos Not sure if your comment means you've realized what the error is, but in case you haven't, you wrote `cout >> mycolor;` instead of `cout << mycolor;` :)

Comment: Now I'm even more embarassed. Anyways, [made the changes but still](http://prntscr.com/6wltu8)

Comment: @AkisKiraleos I can't help you any more by looking at screenshots. Please go to http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/ or http://ideone.com and create an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: or use your own system to make the SSCCE and post its text here of course